# django: sort by foreignkey in model manager

Tags: python, django

```
class Author(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField()

class Article(models.Model):
    author = models.ForeignKey(Author)
    created_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
```

In a custom model manager for `Author`, how could one proceed to sort all the authors by the creation date of their most recent `Article`? Is this possible without using raw sql or for loops?

To show research effort and clarify the question, here's the (pseudo)code of how I'd do that in raw Python. It is untested and would probably not work because of the `if not article.author in sorted_authors` condition.

```
from django.db import models
from .models import Article

class AuthorsManager(models.Manager):
    def get_sorted_authors(self):

        articles = Article.objects.all().order_by('creation_date')

        sorted_authors = []
        for article in articles:
            # not sure if this if condition would work
            if not article.author in sorted_authors:
                sorted_authors.append(article.author)

        return sorted_authors
```

---

Another possible solution: add a `last_article_datetime` field to `Author` and sort by that. Widely more efficient and concise. Question still standing for any other use-case though.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe like this:

```
Author.objects.annotate(lc=Max('article__created_at')).order_by('lc')
```

Comment: Have you tested this, or is this just an idea?